# PHP After every NTH in DIV LOOP

Tags: loops

Hi I want to add content after every 3rd div in the loop. Here is below code but I am not getting even render content "Hi this is the 3d div"

Its not detecting every 3rd div.

```
<?php
    function q_list_item($q_item)
    {
        $count = 0;

        $this->output('<DIV>');
        $this->my_items;    
        $this->output('</DIV>');

        $count++;           

        if($count % 3 == 0) {
            echo 'Hi this is the 3rd div';
        }

    }
?>
```

**----[Actual Function]-----------------------------------------------**

```
<?php

function q_list_item($q_item)
{

    $this->output('<DIV CLASS="qa-q-list-item'.rtrim(' '.@$q_item['classes']).'" '.@$q_item['tags'].'>');

    $this->q_item_stats($q_item);
    $this->q_item_main($q_item);
    $this->q_item_clear();

    $this->output('</DIV> <!-- END qa-q-list-item -->', '');

}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not fluent in PHP, but unless I'm  missing something, your count is getting reset to zero every time this function is called. Since you're declaring count inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting the `$count` to 0 at the top of this function, so it will always be 1 when you run the if statement at the end of the function.

This may help with your issue, although I can't tell if your code is in a class or not as it doesn't look like it is, but you are using `$this->` in there. Essentially, move the instantiation of the counter outside of the function:

```
<?php
    $q_list_count = 0;

    function q_list_item($q_item)
    {
        $q_list_count++;

        $this->output('<DIV>');
        $this->my_items;    
        $this->output('</DIV>');

        if($q_list_count % 3 == 0) {
            echo 'Hi this is the 3rd div';
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: giving error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in`

Comment: @pixelngrain have you posted an entire code sample or just a snippet. You may need to show more of your code if you want the perfect answer. In short, wherever `$this->output` is defined, you need to define `private $q_list_count = 0;` and then use `$this->q_list_count` in your function.

Comment: I have modified the question and added actual function. Please guide me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    function q_list_item($q_item)
    {
        $this->output('<DIV>');
        $this->my_items;    
        $this->output('</DIV>');

        $count++;           

        if($count % 3 == 0) {
            echo 'Hi this is the 3rd div';
        }

    }
?>
```

initialize the $count outside the loop, otherwise count will always be 1 when it reaches the if statement

Comment: giving error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in`